# Why when I set data-backdrop = "false", it can't close modal when I click outside of modal?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

My code like this :

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-4">Bootstrap Modals</h1>

  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h3>The Basic Modal</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="true" >Click to open Modal</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Input data</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"> </textarea>
</div>

<!-- basic modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo and full code like this : https://codepen.io/trendingnews/pen/BayQLrm?editors=1010

I set  data-backdrop="false" to remove backdrop

but it makes me unable to click on something. I have to click the close button on the modal to close on the modal.

how do I make it when I click on any element outside of modal, the modal automatically closed?

for example, I click textarea or other elements, the modal is automatically closed

Comment: Because the backdrop has a listener to close the modal when clicked - you would have to put a listener on the body, but exclude the modal - try change the backdrop color to transparent instead? Not sure if that will work, you'd need to look under the hood in Bootstrap, or set to white with really, really low opacity

Comment: @Darren Sweeney Okay thanks. I add `.modal-backdrop {
   background-color: transparent;
  }`, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extension to my comment, adding as an answer for anyone else that comes across this.

**Problem:**

You want to use a bootstrap modal, with no backdrop, and have the functionality that clicking away from the modal closes it.

**Challenge:**

The bootstrap modal backdrop has a listener on it so when clicked, it closes the modal. However, if there's no backdrop, then this cannot happen.

**Solution:**

Use a backdrop as normal but set it's color to transparent. Set the css `background-color` property on the backdrop e.g.

```
.modal-backdrop { background-color: transparent; }
```